# Remove 'included' Table Name from response - Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Hi I have the following query:

```
    const availAll = await InstructorAvail.findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { date: sun, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: mon, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: tues, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: wed, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: thurs, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: fri, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: sat, instructorId: instructorId },
            ],
        },
        include: [{ model: Timeslots, required: true }],
    })
```

which returns the following, what i would like to achieve is the removal of 'Timeslots.':

```
        {
            "uuid": "cef9aff7-2b2a-4ac4-aa19-95003f5ee00c",
            "date": "09May21",
            "timeslot": "480",
            "timeslotid": 29,
            "status": 1,
            "instructorId": 69,
            "createdAt": "2021-05-10T20:46:45.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-05-10T20:46:45.000Z",
            "Timeslots.id": 29,
            "Timeslots.uuid": "0ff2019f-336c-439b-8876-fb4a44651556",
            "Timeslots.time_integer": 480,
            "Timeslots.name": "08:00 am",
            "Timeslots.period": "morning",
            "Timeslots.createdAt": "2021-05-10T18:52:37.000Z",
            "Timeslots.updatedAt": "2021-05-10T18:52:37.000Z"
        },
```

I would like to streamline the json using attributes and remove "Timeslots." from the response:

```
    const availAll = await InstructorAvail.findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { date: sun, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: mon, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: tues, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: wed, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: thurs, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: fri, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: sat, instructorId: instructorId },
            ],
        },
        attributes: [
            'id',
            'uuid',
            'date',
            'timeslot',
            'status',
            'instructorId',
            'createdAt',
            'updatedAt',
        ],
        include: [{ 
            model: Timeslots, 
            required: true, 
            attributes: [
              ['Timeslots.name', 'name'],
              ['Timeslots.period', 'period'],
         ]}],
    })
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your example code will remove most of the attributes you don't want from the response, if you don't want any from `Timeslots` use `attributes: []`

Comment: thanks for reply, your suggestion was part of the solution. I have just added the complete solution i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally resolved this by amending the code as follows:

```
const availAll = await InstructorAvail.findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { date: sun, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: mon, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: tues, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: wed, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: thurs, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: fri, instructorId: instructorId },
                { date: sat, instructorId: instructorId },
            ],
        },
        attributes: [
            'id',
            'uuid',
            'date',
            'timeslot',
            'status',
            'instructorId',
            'Timeslots.name',  //insert nested table.columnName here
            'Timeslots.period',
        ],
        include: [{ 
            model: Timeslots, 
            required: true, 
            attributes: [] // return nothing from nested table here
        }],
    })
```

This provides me the output:

```
{
                "id": 9127,
                "uuid": "3d642c18-1e86-419c-8f6d-a6fba772e974",
                "date": "27May21",
                "timeslot": "870",
                "timeslotId": 42,
                "status": 1,
                "instructorId": 69,
                "name": "14:30 am",
                "period": "afternoon"
            },
```