# How to 'extract' columns from included tables on Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to 'unwind' columns from an included table of a query, but i'm not getting it right, I've tried the following solution:
[Remove 'included' Table Name from response - Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478107/remove-included-table-name-from-response-sequelize)

Unsucessfully

So far I'm able to create the following query:

```
    include: {
      model: Branches,
      as: 'userBranches',
      include: {
        model: Countries,
        as: 'branchCountry',
        attributes: ['countryName'],
      },
    },
  }),
```

Getting the following:

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "758406e2-47ce-4f1e-b4be-492103ee2f91",
            "whatsappNumber": "5531975080415",
            "whatsappId": "5531975080415",
            "businessName": "Quintal da Dirce",
            "cnpj": "123456789",
            "email": "lepcbelisario@gmail.com",
            "ownerFirstName": "Leandro",
            "ownerMiddleName": "Parisi",
            "ownerLastName": "Carvalho",
            "ownerCpf": "123456789",
            "password": "123456789",
            "botName": "Walle",
            "logo": null,
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.330Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.330Z",
            "userBranches": [
                {
                    "id": "f7488e1d-5fc4-4314-b7bd-f500e6b77c3f",
                    "userId": "758406e2-47ce-4f1e-b4be-492103ee2f91",
                    "managerName": "Leandro",
                    "branchName": "Quintal da Dirce 2000",
                    "countryId": 1,
                    "stateId": 1,
                    "cityId": 1,
                    "neibourhood": "Minha Kombi",
                    "street": "rua da kombui",
                    "streetNumber": "222",
                    "streetComplement": "222",
                    "postalCode": "12345",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "createdAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.347Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.347Z",
                    "branchCountry": {
                        "countryName": "Brazil"
                    }
                },
```

But i would like to get:

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "758406e2-47ce-4f1e-b4be-492103ee2f91",
            "whatsappNumber": "5531975080415",
            "whatsappId": "5531975080415",
            "businessName": "Quintal da Dirce",
            "cnpj": "123456789",
            "email": "lepcbelisario@gmail.com",
            "ownerFirstName": "Leandro",
            "ownerMiddleName": "Parisi",
            "ownerLastName": "Carvalho",
            "ownerCpf": "123456789",
            "password": "123456789",
            "botName": "Walle",
            "logo": null,
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.330Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.330Z",
            "userBranches": [
                {
                    "id": "f7488e1d-5fc4-4314-b7bd-f500e6b77c3f",
                    "userId": "758406e2-47ce-4f1e-b4be-492103ee2f91",
                    "managerName": "Leandro",
                    "branchName": "Quintal da Dirce 2000",
                    **"countryName": "Brazil"**
                    "stateId": 1,
                    "cityId": 1,
                    "neibourhood": "Minha Kombi",
                    "street": "rua da kombui",
                    "streetNumber": "222",
                    "streetComplement": "222",
                    "postalCode": "12345",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "createdAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.347Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-06-26T21:52:03.347Z",
 
                },
```

Any tips?